# ng-pattern for not allowing input of a certain set of characters (e.g. +-!"¤%&/=?)

Tags: regex, angularjs

My question is exactly like my title. I'm writing a directive with an input field inside the template like below:

```
<input name="{{name}}"
           id="{{name}}"
           ng-model="message"
           ng-maxlength="{{length}}"
           maxlength="{{length}}"
           type="text"
           ng-pattern=" ... "
           autocomplete="off"
            />
```

what should I fill in ng-pattern?

Comment: Is that the entire list of "illegal" characters?

Answer (score 0):

I finally use `/[^0-9a-zA-ZøæåÆØÅöÖäÄüÜ\.\*\\,/\():\[\]= &-]/g`
Thanks iismathwizard for mention the whitelist thing.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
^[^+\-!"¤%&\/=?]+$
```

I'm not sure if you have more characters you need to disallow. Perhaps it would be easier to whitelist rather than blacklist "illegal" characters.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tP1cA2/1)